# How to get the random columns from an array in python?

Tags: python, numpy

I wanted to retrieve random columns from a numpy array in python. I have retrieved the random rows by using the code given below:

```
data =  [[1,2,3,4],[3,8,9],[5,3,9]]
random_arr = np.random.randint(0,data.shape[1],2) 
data[random_arr]
```

I want the output as

```
a = [[1,2],
 [3,8],
 [5,3]]

 or

a = [[3,5],
 [8,3],
 [9,9]]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code sample you provided doesn't even run... So here is how you can do both:

Extract random rows:

```
import numpy as np

data = np.array([
    [1, 2, 3, 4],
    [5, 6, 7, 8],
    [9, 10, 11, 12]
])

num_rows_to_extract = 2
random_indices = np.random.choice(data.shape[0], num_rows_to_extract, replace=False)

random_rows = data[random_indices]

print("Random Rows:")
print(random_rows)
```

Extract random columns:

```
import numpy as np

data = np.array([
    [1, 2, 3, 4],
    [5, 6, 7, 8],
    [9, 10, 11, 12]
])

num_cols_to_extract = 2
num_columns = data.shape[1]
random_indices = np.random.choice(num_columns, num_cols_to_extract, replace=False)

random_columns = data[:, random_indices]

print("Random Columns:")
print(random_columns)
```

Please provide full examples like this if you want people to focus on the problem, not the question.

Comment: Ys,Sure . will do